# How to restrict webserver access in IIS 6.0 with specific global AD group only?

Tags: iis, iis-6

We are running the IIS 6.0, and I would like to restrict the webserver access to only allow users in the defined Global AD group. Is that anywhere I do it in the IIS 6.0 administration settings panel? if not where I can set this?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Under **IP Address and Domain Name Restrictions**, click *Edit*.

Do one of the following:

1. To deny access, click **Granted Access**, and then click **Add**. In the **Deny Access On** dialog box that appears, specify the option that you want, and then click **OK**. The computer, group of computers, or domain that you specified is added to the list.
2. To grant access, click **Denied Access**, and then click **Add**. In the **Grant Access On** dialog box that appears, select the option that you want, and then click **OK**. The computer, group of computers, or domain that you selected is added to the list.
3. Click OK.

For more information about "How to configure IIS Web site authentication in Windows Server 2003", you can refer to this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324274/how-to-configure-iis-web-site-authentication-in-windows-server-2003).